# Does ember.js still support ObjectController? If not, what replaces it?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to learn some Ember.js and while I realize everything is in flux and the moment, it seems that this bit of code from the Sproutcore 2 guides (which are linked to at the Ember.js github readme) doesn't work any longer:

```
   App.userController = SC.ObjectController.create({
        content: SC.Object.create({
        firstName: "Albert",
        lastName: "Hofmann",
        posts: 25,
        hobbies: "Riding bicycles"
      })
    });
```

Looking at the ember.js source, the only type of controller that seems to be supported is an arryay controller. Is there an established best practice for proxying between a single model object that is not part of an array/collection and a view? Or do people forego the proxying and simply set up bindings directly between the model and view objects? Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED: Yes, `Ember.ObjectController` is a first-class part of Ember and is most frequently used to proxy a model's properties for easy rendering by templates. See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ObjectController.html for documentation.

Comment: So your model and controller are the same class? Or do you proxy to your model using a separate sublcass of Ember.Object?

Comment: You still want to separate your model and your controller.

Answer (score 10):

There are plans to bring back `ObjectController`/`ObjectProxy`. Peter and I have started working on it [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/objectproxy), but we need to add some lower level functionality to Ember before it can be fully supported.

Until then, you can use `Ember.Object` with a `content` property. You'll have to explicitly reference the content property in property paths (eg. `App.userController.content`). When `ObjectController` is finished you'll be able to switch your controllers to inherit from it instead and you can update your property paths to not explicitly reference `content`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Just getting started with Ember. Subclassing Object will do for now.

Comment: I just ran into this as I was searching for status of `ObjectController`. I assume this has landed in Ember by now, correct? Btw, the link to the issue in the post is broken now.

Answer (score 4):

It's in master now, see: 
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/c6954ba40ab9f007dd499634bfccf40fc31a73d7