# Why isn't my Ember-Rails "Hello World" app working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I've been trying to evaluate emberjs for a rails project.

Can someone suggest (or ideally for my failing project) how get my data to display in the view? I've only run `rails g ember:bootstrap` and created a `User` table with a single attribute `username`.

Link to repo: https://github.com/Rhodee/ember-hello-world

The console provides only these clues:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined application_controller.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined user_controller.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object <Ember.Object:ember282> has no method 'removeArrayObserver' ember.js:11068
```

I've already utilized these resources for study:

- https://github.com/emberjs/data#readme
- http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/26/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/C7LrM/59/
- http://emberjs.com/documentation/

Where can I find up-to-date tutorials reflecting the state of how to get things wired up to simply display an index template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two errors you're seeing are an [open issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/67).

I'm trying to figure this all out, like you. I resolved the errors by changing the boilerplate from

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
```

to

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Object.extend
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and after a bit of digging discovered the following:

The console errors refer to the absence of `Ember.ObjectController` in the current stable ember release. `Ember.ObjectController` used to be in older versions of ember, was taken out, and is now making its way back in as stated in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864337/does-ember-js-still-support-objectcontroller-if-not-what-replaces-it#answer-8868217). There is also a (temporary) solution in that answer.

The *latest* ember release (available via the ember github repo) includes this change, and I've been attempting to use it with ember-rails, whilst reading the [Ember Application Structure Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/). After some more digging, I found that `Ember.State` has since been updated to `Ember.Route`, and there are also some updates to the `connectOutlets` callback, as detailed in [this commit](https://github.com/joliss/ember.js/commit/b35b0aee2e927380cb09bfc56db183a98e358c93).

To quote an ember-rails contributor, [the ember-rails generators are a "mess"](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/67). So you may have to update some of the generated code with the fixes mentioned above.

Alternatively, I'd recommend going through the cerebris tutorial using the exact setup as they have used (available in their example app code).