# Ember.js routing with custom controller mapping

Tags: routes, ember.js

I cannot seem to specify custom controller inside of the `Route.connectOutlets` method.
The idea is I don't want to create empty controllers for each view, well because I don't believe that this is the right implementation in the first place.
In short if I take [Gordon Hempton's example](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-router-example) and slightly update the code in the router items/item route from

```
item: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/:item_id',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
        var item = router.getPath('itemsController.content').objectAt(context.item_id);
        router.get('itemController').set('content', item);
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('item');
      }
    })
```

to

```
item: Ember.Route.extend({
route: '/:item_id',
connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
    var item = router.getPath('itemsController.content').objectAt(context.item_id);
    var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
    applicationController.connectOutlet({ 
        viewClass: router.namespace.ItemView, 
        context: item, 
        controller: applicationController 
    });
  }
})
```

The item selection stops working without any errors.
Did I get something wrong in the code, or scenario with multiple views for controller is just not supported?

UPD:

The ItemView template is as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  {{{description}}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the relevant item as your controller?  This way you avoid creating unused empty controllers and have your item content available to your view.

```
applicationController.connectOutlet({ 
    viewClass: router.namespace.ItemView, 
    controller: item
});
```

Comment: Adding `applicationController.set('content', item);` before `applicationController.connectOutlet` with removing context parameter didn't help.

Comment: I'm referring to the item "var item = router.getPath('itemsController.content').objectAt(context.item_id);".  Try setting the controller of applicationController's outlet to that object.  Manipulating applicationController and connecting itself as it's outlet controller seems to be your problem.

Comment: Updating the connectOutlet call to `applicationController.connectOutlet({ viewClass: router.namespace.ItemView, context: item, controller: router.get('itemsController') });` throws error "Object #<Object> has no method 'addArrayObserver'"

Comment: Yes, it's working. Obviously this is a hack - I couldn't imagine that controller should be something but Controller class instance. And I would expect that the view by default is attached to the controller whose connectOutlet method is invoked. Looks like Ember has lots of surprises, when coming from ASP.NET MVC grounds.

Comment: The concept of a controller in the Ember world is much looser than the ASP.NET MVC world.  Any object and/or collection can be a controller:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864337/does-ember-js-still-support-objectcontroller-if-not-what-replaces-it).